# Redux state not capturing user payload on login

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am building an ecommerce app and using Redux to persist the state of the user as well as the state of the cart. My user's state is not getting captured on login. It appears that a payload is generated on login, but that payload is not getting saved to state. When the user goes to make a purchase, the POST request fails since no information on the user is available when the request is made.

[image: Payload when user logs in]

Here is the user reducer handling the change of state when the user logs in:

[image]

I think a potential issue might be that I am trying to mutate state directly and that I should push in a new state with the payload instead. I'm not sure however. Please let me know if you have any ideas or if you need to see the dispatch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your action.payload doesn’t have a currentUser property that then encapsulates your user properties. Instead your payload has all the properties so your “const { currentUser, accessToken } …” function will set “currentUser” to null since it doesn’t exist in the action.payload object.

Comment: Good catch. The payload has "_id" so I went ahead and passed that to the state with " const {_id, accessToken} = action.payload ... state.currentUser = _id". Thanks for that. I was curious if you know of a better way to mutate state besides what I'm doing here. I think this may not be a functional pattern as I am mutating state directly.

Comment: You have your reducer setup to listen for an action. Then in the reducer are updating the state. As long as you are not directly modifying the state outside of reducers (i.e. without dispatching an action) then I would say this is correct and good practices.